# how to develop UITableView which work like UIPickerView and selected row height is big then other row's in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have created one `UITableView` in `UIViewController` which work's with all same row height but I want to **increase the row height of selected row** than other row's. I want to set row height more which is in **purpole color cell** when it get selected in middle after scrolling. My code and output is as bellow:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
  IBOutlet UITableView *tbl;
  IBOutlet UIScrollView *scr;
  int pos;
}
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    scr.frame = CGRectMake(15, 0, 280, 480);
    scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scr.frame.size.width, 1320 + 480 - 44);
    tbl.frame = CGRectMake(15, 218, 280, 1320);
}

#pragma mark - TableView DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello row no. %ld",(long)[indexPath row]];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - TableView Delegate

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 }

-(void)setscroll:(int)value
{
    [tbl reloadData];
    NSUInteger indexArr[] = {0,value};
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr length:2];

    TableViewCell * theCell = (TableViewCell *)[tbl cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    theCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

    [tbl setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,theCell.center.y-((44*value)+22)) animated:NO];
}

-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    CGFloat rowHeight = 44;  
    NSLog(@"targetContentOffset %f",targetContentOffset->y);
    CGFloat floatVal = targetContentOffset->y / rowHeight;
    NSInteger rounded = (NSInteger)(lround(targetContentOffset->y));
    NSInteger testRounded = (NSInteger)(lround(floatVal));
    NSLog(@"rounded %ld",(long)rounded);
    NSLog(@"testRounded %ld",(long)testRounded);
    if (testRounded<=0)
    {
        [self setscroll:0];
    }
    else if (testRounded<=29)
    {
    [self setscroll:29];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setscroll:testRounded];
    }
}
@end
```

[image: OUTPUT OF Above code is as below screenshot:]

Comment: You know, all those if-else clauses can be replaced by a single line, [self setscroll:testRounded];

Comment: plz, tell me solution of my problem if you have..!!

Comment: U will have to inherit the tableviewcontroller and draw the rect for that centre cell along with whatever color you want. It would get you what you looking for. Also mean while I'll look for other option's too.

Comment: Hey @walle84 plz see the below my solved problem code thanks for comment. now i want to call method on uiscrollvew for refresh the table to see increased height with smoodh scrolling. how can i call method on uiscrollview when user touchup the scroll thanks.. i have tryed scrollview delegates methods but not usefull for me...!

Comment: Far I know increasing height of cell been selected as well as decreasing height of deselected one. The animation of inc or dec won't be smooth. That's why I asked you to go for custom UITableview so you could be at one level below and achieve your smooth scroll with inc or dec height.

Comment: Also I would try out your code and also look into it. If I come up with some alternative then would post here. Also if you get a way do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the correct Solution...!
hear i have need to write code in scrollViewDidScroll: method for get content offset of scrollview for gate the position of selected row. this logic code same as scrollViewWillEndDragging: method just set global variable and write in **scrollViewDidScroll** method last instead of call function.

```
if (testRounded<=0)
{
    Value = 0;
}
else if (testRounded>=29)
{
    Value = 29;
}
else
{
    Value = testRounded;
}
```

then after write add code for refresh table and set selected row height more. :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"value: %ld",(long)Value);
    RowAtIndex = Value;
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, ((RowAtIndex*44)));
    [scr setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    [tbl reloadData];
}
```

and then after **set the height**:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == RowAtIndex)
    {
        return 64;
    }
    else
    {
        return 44;
    }
}
```

and in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** for change the selected cell color:

```
if (RowAtIndex == indexPath.row)
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
}
```

**Output:**

[image]