# How can I change the opacity of unselected cells in a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could change the opacity of the cells that are unselected in a UIPickerView?

The reason I ask is because I am using it as a Font selector, but some of the thin fonts are difficult to see when they are partly transparent, as is the default on a picker.

Here are the cells i would like to make fully opaque;
[image: picker screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: Instead use UITableVIew

Comment: It will be more clear if you add image in your question.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR do you have a link to an example? Thanks

Comment: With `UIPickerView` it's not possible.

Comment: @brontea Take help from here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051945/how-to-develop-uitableview-which-work-like-uipickerview-and-selected-row-height

Comment: @dahiya_boy that is helpful, thanks